# What is the process for updating an iOS In-App Purchase?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I released an app through the Apple App Store with several non-consumable In-App Purchases. I need to update one of the IAPs, so I re-uploaded the archive from Xcode and submitted the IAP for review.  It's currently in the "Waiting for Review" state.  Do I have to update the app itself in order to get the IAP reviewed or will the review be conducted without an app update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only change the metadata of an already released IAP then there is no need to upload the app itself again. Therefore, when your IAPs are already in "Waiting for review" then you're done.

Note: When you add new IAPs then you also need to upload a new binary.